# Is it possible to have a two segments value for the slug rewrite for a custom taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy for `location` that is assigned to two post types which are `post` and `events`.

To make it easier, I have created two separate location taxonomies and assigned each to the two posts types.

Now, my concern is the URL structure. I am hoping to be able to use the same slug which is location for both post type taxonomies.

I have tried setting a two segment value for the rewrite for the `events` `location` taxonomy like:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'events/location' ),
```

This results to the correct URL that I am aiming for but when I try to view the taxonomy page like `mydomain.com/events/location/asia` it goes to a 404 page.

Is what I can trying to do possible in Wordpress? If it is, what am I missing to make the URL work correctly?

Another question is, it possible for me to set a URL rewrite to the location taxonomy assigned to the post post type like:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'posts/location' ),
```

So in my setup, the post and events location taxonomies are registered separately but have a common second segment in the rewritten URL.